# adb not found even if path set in /etc/environment

Tags: 14.04, environment-variables

I installed android-sdk in /opt/android-sdk folder
modified /etc/environment file as below

```
ANDROID_SDK=/opt/android-sdk
PATH=...:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_SDK/tools
```

logged out and login again.
If I type adb or android in terminal it shows command not found.

```
:~$ echo $ANDROID_SDK
/opt/android-sdk

:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_SDK/tools
```

I think I am doing something wrong. Please correct me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please post the output of `ls /opt/android-sdk`.

Answer (score 4):

In `/etc/environment` variable expansion is not performed. You cannot define a variable here and then reference it with `$`. Your path literally includes "$ANDROID_SDK" which is not expanded into `/opt/android-sdk`

If you want to define your path in `/etc/environment` then use the full paths

```
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/opt/android-sdk/tools
```

(and your full JAVA_HOME path which I don't see in your question.)

Rather than defining your path system-wide, you may want to define it locally (generally preferred).

The local version of `/etc/environment` is ~/.pam_environment. This has a slightly different syntax. To set the path here, reference the current path and append your additions like this:

```
PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/opt/android-sdk/tools
```

(and your JAVA_HOME path too after another colon)

You also can use `~/.profile` or in `~/.bashrc` - in these files you can use the normal shell syntax with `$` expansion like you did before.

After you define it, you then need to source the file by doing `source .profile` or whichever file you used, or by logging out and back in. (The exception is `.bashrc` which is sourced every time you start an interactive shell, so opening a new terminal would be enough)

Comment: Actually `~/.pam_environment` can expand variables, but the syntax is different; please see [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables). (OTOH, using `~/.profile` is simpler.)

Answer (score 0):

Well to solve this issue , I recommend you to provide the environmental parameters in the profile. That is kindly add those *ANDROID_SDK* and *PATH* parameters at the bottom of the file **/etc/profile**.
Then logout and login and just see , it will work.

Comment: Better to create a file in the `/etc/profile.d` folder; please see [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables).