# PATH variable not getting updated according to /etc/environment

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I tried adding a path to my PATH variable by making changes in /etc/environments. However, now when I do echo $PATH, the PATH variable contains even lesser path entries than it had earlier. I did reboot my computer too.

It must now be picking the value of PATH variable from some other file or the value being read from etc/environment is now being overridden by some other file.

I am unable to fix this. Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: What was you trying to add?

Comment: Was setting a JAVA_HOME variable. Adding it to the end of existing PATH. Then creating another variable SBT_HOME and adding to the end of PATH variable.

Comment: what exactly did you put in `/etc/environment`?

Comment: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/scala/scala-2.11.8/bin:/usr/local/spark/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin"
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
SBT_HOME=/usr/local/sbt
PATH=$PATH:$SBT_HOME/bin
export PATH

Comment: @Dan see the answer below. `/etc/environment` doesn't work like that. YOu'll add one value per line

Comment: see [this question too](http://askubuntu.com/questions/815452/adb-not-found-even-if-path-set-in-etc-environment) there's no `$` expansion in `/etc/environment` as @Anwar explains

Comment: @Anwar - So if I have to write complete path directly using ':' as separator? If I do not use $ and write just PATH=PATH:JAVA_HOME it wont consider these as variables but plain text?

Comment: Yes @Dan.  That's is what Wiki says

Comment: @Anwar: Please note that the wiki page takes up an alternative to editing `/etc/environment`. When it comes to PATH it's probably better to leave the default `/etc/environment` as is, and modify PATH via a `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest that you remove your adjustments from `/etc/environment`, create the file `/etc/profile.d/my-path-additions.sh`, and give it this contents:

```
PATH="$PATH:/u‌​sr/local/scala/scala‌​-2.11.8/bin:/usr/loc‌​al/spark/spark-2.0.0‌​-bin-hadoop2.7/bin"
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export SBT_HOME=/usr/local/sbt
PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SBT_HOME/bin"
```

Comment: I am trying this. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Glad to hear that, @Dan. :)

Answer (score 0):

From [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fenvironment)

> This file is specifically meant for system-wide environment variable settings. It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line.

So, make sure you're not using scripting there. Only key/value works and should be one assignment per line like this

```
FOO=bar
```

So, if you want to add `JAVA_HOME`, it will be like

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-1.8"
```

Without using any `$` symbol. Also the variable already defined will be treated as plain text in the next line.

If you want to add multiple entry, you'll separate those using `:` separator.

Here is an example (the default line) already found on that file

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Comment: So I cannot use variables like JAVA_HOME and SBT_HOME to contain the specific path and then use them to be appended at the end of PATH. I wanted to do this, because it looks cleaner and I can make changes easily if required later.

Can I use /etc/profile or /etc/bash.bashrc for this? What would be the ideal thing to do?

Comment: No. They will be treated as plain text

Comment: Also, can you please tell me, what is the order in which these files are read(profile, environment, bash.bashrc)? Which one will take precedence over the other?

Comment: @Dan: Please see the answer I posted. `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` files will be sourced after `/etc/environment` is read, and hence override it.

Comment: downvote doesn't work. Opened new terminal and have empty /etc/profile.d folder.  `cat /etc/environment` `PATH="nowork"` `echo $PATH | grep nowork` prints nothing